# Using jquery, How can I iterate every node in xml?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, node.js

I have another question about below example code.

below is index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <style>
            #frm, #raw {display:block; float:left; width:210px},
            #raw {height:150px; width:310px; margin-left:0.5em}
        </style>
        <title> INDEX </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="frm">
            Profile: <select id="profiles">
            <option> </option>
            </select>
            <br></br>

            Format:<select id="formats">
            <option value="json"> JSON </option>
            <option value="xml"> XML </option>
            </select>
            <br></br>
            <div id="output"></div>
        </form>
        <textarea id="raw"></textarea>
    </body>

    <script>
        $.get("http://localhost:8080/profiles",function (profile_names) {
            $.each(profile_names, function (i, pname) {
                $("#profiles").append("<option>" + pname + "</option>");
            });
        }, "json");
        $("#formats, #profiles").change(function () {
            var format = $("#formats").val();
            $.get("http://localhost:8080/profile/" + $("#profiles").val() + "." + format,
                function (profile, stat, jqXHR) {
                    var cT = jqXHR.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
                    $("#raw").val(profile);
                    $("#output").html('');
                    if (cT === "application/json") {
                        $.each($.parseJSON(profile), function (k, v) {
                            $("#output").append("<b>" + k + "</b> : " + v + "<br>");
                        });
                        return;
                    }

                    if (cT === "application/xml") {
                        xmlDoc = $.parseXML( profile ),
                        $xml = $( xmlDoc );
                        $($xml).each(function(){
                            $("#output").append($(this).text() + "<br/>");
                         });
                    }
                }, 
            "text");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

Second, server.js file

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var profiles = require('./profiles');
var xml2js = require('xml2js');

var index = fs.readFileSync('index.html');
var routes, mimes = {xml: "application/xml", json: "application/json"}

function output(content, format, rootNode) {
    if (!format || format === 'json') {
        return JSON.stringify(content);
    }
    if (format === 'xml') {
        return (new xml2js.Builder({rootName: rootNode})).buildObject(content);
    }
}

routes = {
    'profiles': function (format) {
        return output(Object.keys(profiles), format);
    },
    '/profile': function (format, basename) {
        return output(profiles[basename], format, basename);
    }
};

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
var dirname = path.dirname(request.url),
    extname = path.extname(request.url),
// $.get('http://localhost:8080/profile/' + $('#profiles').val() + '.' + format
    basename = path.basename(request.url, extname);

    extname = extname.replace('.', ''); //remove period


    response.setHeader("Content-Type", mimes[extname] ||'text/html');

    if (routes.hasOwnProperty(dirname)) {
        response.end(routes[dirname](extname, basename));
        return;
    }
    if (routes.hasOwnProperty(basename)) {
        response.end(routes[basename](extname));
        return;
    }
    response.end(index);    
}).listen(8080);
```

below is profiles.js file

```
module.exports = {
    ryan: {
        name: "Ryan Dahl",
        irc: "ryah",
        twitter: "ryah",
        github: "ry",
        location: "San Francisco, USA",
        description: "Creator of node.js"
    },
    isaac: {
        name: "Isaac Schlueter",
        irc: "isaacs",
        twitter: "izs",
        github: "isaacs",
        location: "San Francisco, USA",
        description: "Former project gatekeeper, CTO npm, Inc."
    }
};
```

at index.html file,

After **if (cT === "application/xml") {** is not working properly compare to JSON one.

Actually, the original example code was like this

```
if (cT === "application/xml") {
    profile = jqXHR.responseXML.firstChild.childNodes;
    $.each(profile, function (k, v) {
    if (v && v.nodeType === 1) {
        $("#output").append("<b>" + v.tagName + "</b> : " + v.textContent + "<br>");
    }
});
```

but above one was not working so I searched a way to show all the child node and text at the

selected one.

Is there any way for XML to show the same format as JSON selected at index.html file?

Thank you for understanding dissy question!!!

Comment: isn't `$xml.children()` what you want to iterate over? As here you are trying to iterate over the root element which should be single. By the way `$xml` is already a jQuery element, probably why prefixed by $, so no need to wrap it up again `$($xml)` this is enough `$xml`

Comment: @gilesc I found new way to show their each child element name and text. you can see answer for this question. and about $($xml) things, I just reference [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) here. I do not know the exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way exactly what I want to show for element name and text.

```
if (cT === "application/xml") {
    var xmlDoc =$.parseXML( profile );
    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var kids = $xml.children().children();
    kids.each(function(){
        var tagName=this.tagName;
        var val=$(this).text();
        $("#output").append("<b>" + tagName + "</b> : " + val + "<br>");
    });     
}
```

I do not know why but when profile is parsed for 'tj', below is the result.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tj>
  <name>TJ Holowaychuk</name>
  <irc>tjholowaychuk</irc>
  <twitter>tjholowaychuk</twitter>
  <github>visionmedia</github>
  <location>Victoria, BC, Canada</location>
  <description>Author of express, jade and many other modules</description>
</tj>
```

So first child of the $xml is `<tj> </tj>`. so I used children() method twice and then

I can iterate all of `<tj> </tj>e`s child and then print child's name and text.

Is there someone who can explain my code clearly

Please let me know.

Thank you.